# Why is my beer black?

Tags: rendering, volumetrics

I've been following this blender guru tutorial ([Link to relevant section of tutorial](https://youtu.be/Xbc3KMIOuKM?t=22m30s))

However, once I try to render the beer material it is coming out black

[image]

I've followed very closely with the tutorial and I can't figure out why i'm getting what i'm getting. A similar question has been asked before, but the solution did not solve my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

My .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: Here is the blend [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2754" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2754/)

Comment: flip the normals of the beer (the actual liquid not the glass), and I think you may have some slight overlap near the top of the liquid (slightly overlapping with the glass)

Comment: ...you may have rendered a Guinnes... :D I examined the file, and the tut, and I would try to decrease volume absorption density (try around 15-20, you have 65)... and, also what @christai said above, and... your meshes have doubles.